# How to get a flexbox not to use more space than the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am building a modal, and want it to be centred in my page and grow organically but only until it reaches a certain width and height.

I center this modal (`.modal`) with flexbox, and it works fine.

Inside this modal I have another flexbox (`.modal-content`), with a body (`.modal-content__body`) and a footer (`.modal-content__footer`) element. I want the body to grow until the whole `.modal` reaches my `max-height`, at which point I want the `modal-content__body` to start scrolling vertically.

The HTML hierarchy is:

```
.modal-container // Full screen
  .modal // Centred box with max-width and max-height
    .modal-content // The content of the modal
      .modal-content__body // Potentially growing content
      .modal-content__footer
```

I can't get the `.modal-content` not to overflow. It simply ignores the parent's (`.modal`) height and grows to provide space for the content.

If I *remove* the additional div of the `.modal-content` and simply merge the `.modal` with the `.modal-content` **it works as expected**, but because I'm using a framework (Angular) I can't change the way the HTML elements are encapsulated.

(**NOTE**: If I set `max-height: -webkit-fill-available;` on the `.modal-content` it works, but this property is not well supported so I can't use it)

Here is a code demonstrating the issue:

```css
/* Centers the child */
.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* The box in the middle, that should grow
   organically, but be restricted as well */
.modal,
.modal-content--merged-with-modal {
  width: 30rem;
  max-width: calc(50vw - 3rem);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
  /* Irrelevant styling */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.modal-content__body {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  /* Irrelevant styling */
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}

.modal-content__footer {
  /* Irrelevant styling */
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0.75rem;
}


/* Irrelevant styling to present the problem */

html {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

section {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <section class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-content modal-content--merged-with-modal">
      <div class="modal-content__body">
        <code>BODY // </code> srollable<br>
        <br> Container resizes as expected when<br> the container height is reduced.<br>
        <br> In this case, the modal is the same<br> element, as the flexbox handling<br> the body and the footer.<br> .
        <br> .
        <br> .
        <br> .
        <br> .
        <br> .
        <br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-content__footer">
        <code>FOOTER // </code> Works
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-content__body">
          <code>BODY // </code>simply grows<br>
          <br> Container overflows when<br> the container height is reduced.<br>
          <br> In this case, the modal <strong>contains</strong><br> the flexbox, that handles the<br> body and the footer.<br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content__footer">
          <code>FOOTER // </code> Doesn't work
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: Instead of using `overflow-y: scroll;` it's better to use `overflow-y: auto;`, to remove the scrollbar when not needed.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh completely right. Just added it to make it easier to see the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple fix is to make the `.modal` a flex container with column direction.

```css
/* Centers the child */
.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
/* The box in the middle, that should grow
   organically, but be restricted as well */
.modal, .modal-content--merged-with-modal {
  width: 30rem;
  max-width: calc(50vw - 3rem);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);

  /* Irrelevant styling */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
  
  
.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}
  
.modal-content__body {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  /* Irrelevant styling */
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
  
  
.modal-content__footer {
  /* Irrelevant styling */
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
.modal {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}
  
  
/* Irrelevant styling to present the problem */
html {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <section class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal-content modal-content--merged-with-modal">
      <div class="modal-content__body">
        <code>BODY // </code> srollable<br>
        <br>
        Container resizes as expected when<br>
        the container height is reduced.<br>
        <br>
        In this case, the modal is the same<br>
        element, as the flexbox handling<br>
        the body and the footer.<br>
        .<br>
        .<br>
        .<br>
        .<br>
        .<br>
        .<br>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-content__footer">
        <code>FOOTER // </code> Works
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-content__body">
          <code>BODY // </code>simply grows<br>
          <br>
          Container overflows when<br>
          the container height is reduced.<br>
          <br>
          In this case, the modal <strong>contains</strong><br>
          the flexbox, that handles the<br>
          body and the footer.<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content__footer">
          <code>FOOTER // </code> Doesn't work
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

**Why?**

Initially the `.modal` was a block element with a `max-height` set and the default overflow behavior (when there is an overflow) is `visible` and you are facing an overflow issue.

By making the `.modal` a flex container, you introduce the **shrink** effect as by default the flex item will have `flex-shrink:1` so its height won't go beyond the height of the flex container (it will shrink to fit) and you will have the need result.

*You may set `flex-shrink:0` to `.modal-content` and you will see the same overflow issue as if there is no `display:flex`*.

Comment: Oh nice... that works thanks. In my case though, I have actually about 3 additional elements between the `.modal` and the `.modal-content`, so how would I do that in this case?

Comment: @enyo I would say make them all flex container ... it's sounds a bit strange, but by making them flex container you change how the height is caclucated .. I will try to add an explanation to this

Comment: @enyo I added an explanation ;)

Comment: That works! It's as clean a solution as I was hoping for, but it's fine! thanks.

Comment: This is a good solution (+1), but a workaround. I'm putting together an alternative that may be more of a natural fix.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the [**`overflow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property to work, it needs a fixed length limitation.

*From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):*

> In order for `overflow` to have an effect, the block-level container must have either a set height (`height` or `max-height`) or `white-space` set to `nowrap`.

In your code, there is no height limitation on `.modal-content__body` (where the `overflow` is set):

```
.modal-content__body {
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Nor is there a height limitation on the parent:

```
.modal-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

`flex-basis: 0` – the relevant component of `flex: 1` in `.modal-content__body` – isn't enough to trigger the overflow condition. But look what happens if you switch to `flex-basis: 100px`

```css
/* Centers the child */
.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
/* The box in the middle, that should grow
   organically, but be restricted as well */
.modal, .modal-content--merged-with-modal {
  width: 30rem;
  max-width: calc(50vw - 3rem);
  max-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);

  /* Irrelevant styling */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
  
  
.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}
  
.modal-content__body {
  flex: 1 0 100px; /* new for demo 1 */
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  /* Irrelevant styling */
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
  
  
.modal-content__footer {
  /* Irrelevant styling */
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
  
  
  
/* Irrelevant styling to present the problem */
html {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-content__body">
          <code>BODY // </code>simply grows<br>
          <br> Container overflows when<br> the container height is reduced.<br>
          <br> In this case, the modal <strong>contains</strong><br> the flexbox, that handles the<br> body and the footer.<br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br> .
          <br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content__footer">
          <code>FOOTER // </code> Doesn't work
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

The scrolling works. A height limitation made the difference.

Here's a potential solution:

Since the height of `.modal` (the parent) and `modal-content` (the child) are the same, move the dimensions from the parent to the child. This brings the height limitation close enough to the content items to trigger the overflow.

Instead of this:

```
.modal {
    width: 30rem;
    max-width: calc(50vw - 3rem);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
}

.modal-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
}
```

Try this:

```
.modal {    }

.modal-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 0;
    width: 30em;
    max-width: calc(50vw - 3rem);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
}
```

```css
/* Centers the child */
.modal-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
/* The box in the middle, that should grow
   organically, but be restricted as well */
.modal, .modal-content--merged-with-modal {


  /* Irrelevant styling */
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  border-radius: 3px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}
  
  
.modal-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;   
     width: 30rem;
     max-width: calc(50vw - 3rem);
     max-height: calc(100vh - 3rem);
}
  
.modal-content__body {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;

  /* Irrelevant styling */
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.1);
}
  
  
.modal-content__footer {
  /* Irrelevant styling */
  border-top: 1px solid silver;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
  
  
  
/* Irrelevant styling to present the problem */
html {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}
main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  display: flex;
}
section {
  flex: 1;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<main>

  <section class="modal-container">
    <div class="modal">

      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-content__body">
          <code>BODY // </code>simply grows<br>
          <br>
          Container overflows when<br>
          the container height is reduced.<br>
          <br>
          In this case, the modal <strong>contains</strong><br>
          the flexbox, that handles the<br>
          body and the footer.<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
          .<br>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-content__footer">
          <code>FOOTER // </code> Doesn't work
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>

</main>
```

Comment: By the way i agree with the second part as the solution as it's almost what he thought about ... he was trying to merge the HTML and since he cannot do it he didn't thing about merging the CSS like you did.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, not sure what you mean... they both seem to work identically now... https://jsfiddle.net/0h5tvabh/1/ (the `flex-basis: 100px` was just an example to show the scroll working; it wasn't an overall solution)

Comment: yes I see, I thought your first explanation was a solution using flex-basis but it was a simple explanation of the issue ;)