# Getting scrollbars to work on a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a parent `div` with fixed or calculated height and width. The aside is fixed width and the content is very large. The source code is below.

[image: actual result]

- The parent (blue) may inside an other container, so the size is uncertain.
- The aside (green) has fixed width.
- The content container (purple) has grow width, which will fill the rest of the width while the actual content is very little.
- The large content (orange) has very large content.

My desire is when the content become large, the scrollbar should appear at the content container (purple). But when i set `overflow: auto;` to parent and container, the vertical scrollbar appeared but the horizontal one in the bottom of the parent container.

The one solution is set the fixed width to the purple container such as `width: calc(100vw - 100px)`. But I'm very confused why the purple width is larger than the `blue - green` even I set the overflow property.

[image: desired result]

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eragzy

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.aside {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.content {
  /* width: calc(400px - 130px); */
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.large {
  background: orange;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="aside">
    aside (fix width)
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="large">
      large content (need scrollbar)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The parent which is `.p` should have `overflow: hidden;` the `.content` should have  `overflow: auto;` to be able to **scroll** inside the wanted element and here the part that you can play with.

**horizontal** `.large {width: 2000px; height: 100%;}` you have to give **fixed width**

**Vertical** `.large {height: 2000px; width: 100%;}` you have to give **fixed height**

First approach with **scroll horizontal**

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.aside {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: purple;
  overflow: auto;
}

.large {
  background: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="aside">
    aside (fix width)
  </div>
  <div class="content"> 
    <div class="large">
      large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
       large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
       large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second approach with **scroll vertical**

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.aside {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.content {
  padding: 10px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: purple;
  overflow: auto;
}

.large {
  background: orange;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="aside">
    aside (fix width)
  </div>
  <div class="content"> 
    <div class="large">
      large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
       large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
       large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
            large content (need scrollbar)
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may misunderstand my question. The `.large` content is auto calculated and should not be set in a actual width or height. When I set the `overflow: hidden` to `.p`, the horizontal scrollbar is missing.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
.content {
  /* width: calc(400px - 130px); */
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

You have `flex-basis` set to `auto`. I think that's what is killing the `overflow` effect.

[The `overflow` property won't function without a fixed length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414392/3597276). That's why it works when you enable `width: calc(400px - 130px)`. But it can also work if there is a fixed length on an ancestor.

Try using just this:

```
.content {
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/erwpzE?editors=1100)

```css
.p {
  display: flex;
  background: blue;
  padding: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

.aside {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.content {
  /* width: calc(400px - 130px); */
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
  /* flex: 1 0 auto; */
  overflow: auto;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
  /* overflow-y: auto; */
}

.large {
  background: orange;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  <div class="aside">
    aside (fix width)
  </div>
  <div class="content"> 
    <div class="large">
      large content (need scrollbar)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this solution leaves another issue. When the `.large` content is not so large to fill all the remain area, the width is less than `calc(400px - 130px)`

Comment: Get those elements to consume free space with `flex-grow: 1`, or the shorthand `flex: 1`. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pVXxZv?editors=1100